# Problem with integral calculus via function "trapz" in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

someone can help me with this problem. I have to calculate the integral with the function trapz of Matlab increasing the mesh intervals N. I need to do this until I reach tolerance.

```
N = 1; %Initial number of mesh intervals
t = [t0,tf]; %Create an initial mesh
y = L(t); %Evaluate the function at mesh points

I = trapz(t,y); %Compute the integral numerically using trapz

epsilon = I;

while epsilon >= tol % Until I reach tolerance
    
    N = N+1;
    tstep = (tf-t0)/N;
    t1 = t0:tstep:tf;
    y1 = L(t1);
    I_new = trapz(t1,y1); 
    epsilon = I_new - I;
    I = I_new;
   
    
end
```

The problem is that i have always the same value of I_new, don't increase never.

Comment: I would look at your while loop. I would make it while true and add a break in the loop to exit out of the loop when the difference is less than the tolerance.

Comment: Please provide code that can be run. `t0,`, `tf`, `L` are undefined

Answer (score 1):

Implement an abs on your epsilon calculation to to avoid negative values in the while loop evaluation. i.e.

```
epsilon = abs(I_new - I);
```

or

```
abs(epsilon) >= tol
```

Would also recommend setting your initial epsilon value as inf: `epsilon = inf;`